# The type or namespace name 'MediaTypeHeaderValue' could not be found

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I created a C# project using

```
cd /tmp
dotnet new console -o mydotnetapp
cd mydotnetapp
```

then I replaced the code in Program.cs with code that sends a web request with a custom Content-Type header:

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:8888/");

request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

request.Content = new StringContent("18233982904");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

and I ran it using `dotnet run` and I get this error:

```
/private/tmp/mydotnetapp/Program.cs(8,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MediaTypeHeaderValue' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/private/tmp/mydotnetapp/mydotnetapp.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

What am I doing wrong? This seems like an issue with me using an old version of the HTTP library, but my .csproj file says I'm using .NET 6

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is part of System.Net.Http.Headers' namespace.

you need to add this.

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
```